# Removing vertical separation bar in google bar chart

Tags: google-visualization

How can i hide the vertical bar that separates the values on the left and the bars on the right?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for bar charts, set `hAxis.baselineColor` to `'transparent'`, to *hide the vertical bar*

set `hAxis.gridlines.count` to zero, so the baseline isn't replaced with a gridline

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart(transparent) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addRows([
    ['UK', 8.94],
    ['AF', 10.49],
    ['UN', 20.2],
    ['SK', 21.45],
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    hAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'transparent',
      gridlines: {
        count: 0
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'magenta'
    },
    width: 200
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartDiv);
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```